# LaunchDaemons not launching my app, but LaunchAgents launchs it instead

Tags: macos, sh

I am developing an app, in this case for macOS. My app has two parts:

- A GUI
- A Server

From the GUI i can start and stop the serve. My problem is that i need the server starts when the mac boots. Using the LaunchAgents i got to launch it when the user logins on, but i need to initiate it before.

I saw that i need to saving my .plis inside of /Library/LaunchDaemons. I did it but when i restart the computer the server didn t initiate.

I checked that my service gave me the status 1 so, it didn t launch correctly. Maybe the failure is inside the plist... but i dont understand why it works in LaunchAgent and not inside LaunchDaemons

My plist is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.turnoffpc.turnoffpcplist</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/Turn Off PC.app/Contents/Resources/Turn Off PC/Server/dist/turn_off_pc_server.app/Contents/MacOS/turn_off_pc_server</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

For loading the service im using the following sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Copiar el archivo plist a /Library/LaunchDaemons/
sudo cp com.turnoffpc.turnoffpcplist.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/

# Establecer los permisos adecuados
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.turnoffpc.turnoffpcplist.plist
sudo chmod 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.turnoffpc.turnoffpcplist.plist

# Descargar y luego cargar el servicio utilizando launchctl
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.turnoffpc.turnoffpcplist.plist
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.turnoffpc.turnoffpcplist.plist
```

I checked that the service is in the correct location

The path to my app is: inside /Applications/Turn Off PC.app/Resources/Turn Off PC/Server/dist/turn_off_pc_server.app/Contents/MacOS/turn_off_pc_server

Does someone see the error or the thing that i am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

I tried all the above

Comment: Is the thing you're trying to launch a GUI application, or a command-line-type tool? Launch daemons run in a non-gui context, so they need to be written like command-line tools, not like GUI applications.

Comment: No. The software it is a executable without GUI. Now it is solved because i did a workaround, i used crontab

Answer (score 0):

Finally i used contaba, with this manner it is solved

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).